# Is the pi right for a key fob?

Tags: pi-zero, cars

So im working on this project car and i want to have the coolest key fob ever. Theres videos of people making concept key fobs with touch screens and software running like a smartphone. i want to create something like that, just a simple input screen and simple OS to control locking and unlocking the car. So the functionality of a wireless key is not only easy but many many aftermarket products exist that do this. What i need help with is figuring out what the right hardware would be for this project specifically the processor. So small batteries and screens and radio emitters are easy, but making a motherboard and processor the size of a key fob is difficult. The raspberry Pi zero w is too large for this, but im wondering if theres a way to break the board to get rid of parts i wont be using and still have it run code i write, output visuals to the screen and control another board responsible for communicating with the car. If not is there another smaller processor/board that could do this. It has to draw very low power and be capable of running custom software. Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome. W.r.t. the low powerness of a Pi (which it has not) some of these [questions](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=portable+power) are worth a look. As for breaking the board and obtain something that still works in the end: that's rather unlikely... not to mention that connectors you will need, i.e. the powering micro USB and the GPIO to interconnect to the rest of your device are at diametrically opposed corners of the board.

Answer (score 1):

The smallest PCBs you can choose to realize a Key Fob are:

- Arduino Nano
- Arduino Lilypad
- MicroBit
- Adafruit trinket